# Stop letters from moving

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm writing a webpage where you have a line of text with a few different letters and when you hover over some a drop down appears and you can click things in the drop down in order to change the letters.

The problem: When the letters are changed the text on the screen moves around making it very hard to read.

Question: Is it possible to disable this feature and have the letters change without moving all the other text around?

```js
function changeU() {
  document.getElementById("lang").textContent = "U";
}

function changeOH2() {
  document.getElementById("con").textContent = "OH2";
}

function changeOHP() {
  document.getElementById("con").textContent = "OHP";
}

function changeOH1() {
  document.getElementById("con").textContent = "OH1";
}

function changeNCG() {
  document.getElementById("con").textContent = "NCG";
}

function changeNC5() {
  document.getElementById("con").textContent = "NC5";
}

function changeC73() {
  document.getElementById("con").textContent = "C73";
}

function changeCLI() {
  document.getElementById("con").textContent = "CLI";
}

function changeCSA() {
  document.getElementById("con").textContent = "CSA";
}

function changeAMI() {
  document.getElementById("con").textContent = "AMI";
}

function changeBSB() {
  document.getElementById("con").textContent = "BSB";
}

function changeDIS() {
  document.getElementById("con").textContent = "DIS";
}

function changeQ() {
  document.getElementById("x").textContent = "Q";
}

function changeD() {
  document.getElementById("x").textContent = "D";
}

function changeO2() {
  document.getElementById("g").textContent = "O";
}

function changeA() {
  document.getElementById("g").textContent = "A";
}

function changeV() {
  document.getElementById("g").textContent = "V";
}

function change2() {
  document.getElementById("g").textContent = "2";
}

function changeC2() {
  document.getElementById("g").textContent = "C";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.dropbtn {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
  top: 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 195px;
  left: 645px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {}

.dropbtn2 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
  top: 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content2 {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 195px;
  left: 700px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content2 a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown2:hover .dropdown-content2 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown2:hover .dropbtn2 {}

.dropbtn3 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
  top: 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown3 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content3 {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 195px;
  left: 632px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content3 a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown3:hover .dropdown-content3 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown3:hover .dropbtn3 {}

.dropbtn4 {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightgray;
  color: black;
  top: 1px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown4 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content4 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 195px;
  left: 696px;
}

.dropdown-content4 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown4:hover .dropdown-content4 {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown4:hover .dropbtn4 {}

#code {
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  left: 600px;
}

#lang {
  position: relative;
  top: 125px;
  left: 655px;
  font-size: 38px;
}

#con {
  position: relative;
  top: 125px;
  left: 700px;
  font-size: 38px;
}

#x {
  position: relative;
  top: 125px;
  left: 632px;
  font-size: 38px;
}

#g {
  position: relative;
  top: 125px;
  left: 696px;
  font-size: 38px;
}

#hl {
  position: relative;
  top: 229px;
  left: 1025px;
  font-size: 38px;
}

.square {
  position: relative;
  border: solid 5px #000;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  float: right;
  top: 500px;
}

.language {
  position: absolute;
  top: 650px;
  left: 50px;
}

.coninfo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 650px;
  left: 200px;
}

[contenteditable] {
  outline: 0px solid transparent;
}

.xinfo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 650px;
  left: 520px;
}

.ginfo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 650px;
  left: 780px;
}

.save {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="code">NL⠀⠀-⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀-⠀⠀⠀-</h1>
<h1 id="hl" contenteditable="true">HLHLHL</h1>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"><h1 id="lang">L</h1></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <button id="U" onclick="changeU()">U=NFPA (USA)</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown2">
  <button class="dropbtn2"><h1 id="con">CON⠀C</h1></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content2">
    <button id="OH2" onclick="changeOH2()">Diamond 2/3/Diamond Care</button>
    <button id="OHP" onclick="changeOHP()">Diamond 2/3/DC-Plug & Play</button>
    <button id="OH1" onclick="changeOH1()">Diamond 1</button>
    <button id="NCG" onclick="changeNCG()">Chemetron 400</button>
    <button id="NC5" onclick="changeNC5()">Chemetron 500</button>
    <button id="C73" onclick="changeC73()">Series 73</button>
    <button id="CLI" onclick="changeCLI()">Litharge Series</button>
    <button id="CSA" onclick="changeCSA()">Series A</button>
    <button id="AMI" onclick="changeAMI()">Amico</button>
    <button id="BSB" onclick="changeBSB()">Beacon Series B</button>
    <button id="DIS" onclick="changeDIS()">D.I.S.S</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown3">
  <button class="dropbtn3"><h1 id="x">X</h1></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content3">
    <button id="Q" onclick="changeQ()">Ohmeda</button>
    <button id="D" onclick="changeD()">DISS</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown4">
  <button class="dropbtn4"><h1 id="g">G</h1></button>
  <div class="dropdown-content4">
    <button id="O2" onclick="changeO2()">OXY</button>
    <button id="A" onclick="changeA()">MEDICAL AIR</button>
    <button id="V" onclick="changeV()">VAC (2 PORT ONLY)</button>
    <button id="2" onclick="change2()">N20</button>
    <button id="C2" onclick="changeC2()">CO2</button>
  </div>
</div>

<p class="square"><br><br>Note: Conversation tool requirement <br> O-VC-OH1-TOOL for OH1, NCG <br> O-CPB-TOOLKIT for C73</p>
<p class="language">L=Language<br>U=NFPA(USA)
  <p class="coninfo">CON = Conversion Type<br>OH2 = Diamond 2/3/Diamond Care<br>OHP = Diamond 2/3/DC-Plug & Play<br>OH1 = Diamond 1<br>NCG = Chemetron 400<br>NC5 = Chemetron 500<br>C73 = Series 73<br>CLI = Litharge Series<br>CSA = Series A<br>AMI = Amico<br>BSB = Beacon
    Series B<br>DIS = D.I.S.S</p>
  <p class="xinfo">X = Front Connection Type<br>Q = Ohmeda<br>D = DISS
    <p class="ginfo">G = Gas<br>O = OXY<br>A = MEDICAL AIR<br>V = VAC(2 PORT ONLY)<br>2 = N2O<br>C = CO2</p>
    <button class="save" onclick="window.print()">Save</button>
```

Comment: How did you force edit my post?

Comment: Once you gain enough reputation on the site, you can edit questions & answers with approval. With some more reputation you don't need approval.

Comment: @MaxSinger, users with enough reputation can edit other users posts. For future cases, have in mind that a code snippet helps community to help you.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that was a thing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit

Comment: Does anyone know how I can fix my code?

Comment: There's a lot of code you just dumped on us; give the volunteers who answer questions here a little time, huh? :)

Comment: Sorry my bad :(

Comment: Your page is impossible to read. You need to not have all these position:absolute  - perhaps start from a simpler page. Your CSS is messing up any kind of useful information

Comment: without the position:absolute tag the top: and left: tags both do not work.

Comment: Also the HTML is invalid. You are nesting paragraphs

Comment: I suppose i could put it in the body though

Comment: Not sure what the means sorry

Comment: Can you perhaps post a picture of expected result? Since we are not subject matter experts it is really hard to guess what you are trying to achieve

Comment: `<p class="language">L=Language<br>U=NFPA(USA)` is not closed before you have another `<p ....>`

Comment: If you hover over the text "CON" in the middle of the screen and then select one of the options in the drop down it will change the letters like its supposed to but it will also jumble everything up and move it around I want the letters to change and the text on the screen to stay where it is

Comment: looks closed to me its just on the line under it

Comment: @HereticMonkey is this question difficult I thought it would just be a css tag..

Comment: I was waiting for you to post a picture of the expected result as @mplungjan requested. The reason things move around so much is that you've marked almost everything as `position: relative` and predicting where a relatively positioned grandchild of a relatively positioned grandparent and parent is going to end up gets into some serious math. I'd scrap what you have and start over, using absolutely positioned everything or nothing.

Comment: Alright. Will do thank you.